# scroll view, collection view and one page control

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a scroll view and a collection view in one screen .. the scroll view have a page control and the collection view doesn't have a page control..

The problem is when i scroll in the collection view .. the page control of the scroll view change its current page!

How to stop this? and make the page control only changes when i scroll in the scrollview?

here's my code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return images.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "homenewscell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! HomeNewsCollectionViewCell
    cell.date.text = dates[indexPath.item]
    cell.img.image = UIImage(named: images[indexPath.item])
    cell.title.text = titles[indexPath.item]
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = newsSlide.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! HomeNewsCollectionViewCell
    self.newsId = cell.id.text!
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "news", sender: self)
    }

}


 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    newsSlide.delegate = self
    newsSlide.dataSource = self


    slides = createSlides()
    setupSlideScrollView(slides: slides)

    pageControl.numberOfPages = slides.count
    pageControl.currentPage = 0
    view.bringSubviewToFront(pageControl)

}
 func createSlides() -> [banner] {

    let slide1:banner = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("banner", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! banner
    print(banners[0].image.src)
     slide1.img.downloaded(from:banners[0].image.src)
    slide1.clipsToBounds = true
    //slide1.img.image = UIImage(named: "bannerex")
    slide1.img.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped)))

    let slide2:banner = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("banner", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! banner
    slide2.img.downloaded(from:banners[1].image.src)
    //slide2.img.image = UIImage(named: "bannerex")
    slide2.clipsToBounds = true
    slide2.img.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped)))

    let slide3:banner = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("banner", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! banner
    slide3.img.downloaded(from:banners[2].image.src)
    //slide3.img.image = UIImage(named: "bannerex")
    slide3.clipsToBounds = true
    slide3.img.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped)))

    return [slide1, slide2, slide3]
}

@objc func tapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    print("tapped")
    print(pageControl.currentPage)
    let lang = MOLHLanguage.isArabic() ? "ar" : "en"
    UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "\(APIManager.APIList.baseUrl + lang + banners[pageControl.currentPage].link)")!)

}

func setupSlideScrollView(slides : [banner]) {
    scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width * CGFloat(slides.count), height: view.frame.height)
    scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true

    for i in 0 ..< slides.count {
        slides[i].frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
        scrollView.addSubview(slides[i])
    }
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let pageIndex = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x/view.frame.width)
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageIndex)
}
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
   guard scrollView != collectionView else { return }
   let pageIndex = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x/view.frame.width)
   pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageIndex)
}
```

or

```
guard scrollView == self.scrollView else { return }
```